# web api returning html instead of json

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I've created an asp.net core project and in the project I have an angularjs application and also a web api project. The angularjs application loads when I login via postman I get the response I expect in json. But when I try the same in angularjs I get the response in html.

I've tried quite a few settings but unable to get this working.

Tried setting the $http services header, and $httpProvider header but unable to get this working in angular js.

I set the content-type in postman to application/json and it works so not think its because the content-type is wrong in angular js.

Startup.cs file:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services
        .AddMvcCore()
        .AddJsonFormatters();

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(
         options =>
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new 
          CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()

        );
```

The controller in web api is:

```
    [Route("test3")]
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Test3([FromBody]LoginUserRequest model)
    {
        LoginUserResponse response = new LoginUserResponse();
        response.validLogin = false;
        response.Message = "failed" + model.Email;
        return Json(response);
    }
```

Angular js service:

```
   vm.getLogin = getLogin;

    function getLogin(request) {
        return $http.post('/webapi/account/test3',request,{
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}  
        })
            .then(getLoginComplete)
            .catch(getLoginFailed);


    }

    function getLoginComplete(data, status, headers, config) {

        return data.data;
    }

    function getLoginFailed(e) {
        var newMessage = 'XHR Failed for login';
        if (e.data && e.data.description) {
            newMessage = newMessage + '\n' + e.data.description;
        }
        e.data.description = newMessage;

        return {"error":true, "message":"Unable to login please try again later"};
    }
```

Chrome network via developer tools:

> Request URL:http://localhost:5000/webapi/account/test3
>   Request Method:POST
>   Status Code:200 OK
>   Remote Address:[::1]:5000
>   Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
>   Response Headers
>   view source
>   Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
>   Date:Tue, 11 Jul 2017 19:58:46 GMT
>   Server:Kestrel
>   Transfer-Encoding:chunked
>   Request Headers
>   view source
>   Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
>   Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
>   Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
>   Connection:keep-alive
>   Content-Length:61
>   Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
>   Host:localhost:5000
>   Origin:http://localhost:5000
>   Referer:http://localhost:5000/login

Comment: Please post the body(content) of the response for the request.

Comment: https://a.uguu.se/lGIhGSN8hVNF_response

Comment: Had to upload the file to hosting site as too large to paste. This is the body response that I get back in angular service getLoginComplete

Comment: It seems that you get redirected from Test3 to some other method due to authentication so due to that this thing happening.

Comment: mostly. this happens when your path for API is wrong or your server configuration has some errors. what you did is correct there is nothing problem with that

Comment: The response that gets returned is the index page of the application ngview tag is present. Any other ideas where I have gone wrong? Html is getting returned instead of json. Just think i'm missing some config in startup json formatter not sure what though

Comment: thanks sibi raj you were right api path was wrong